permission problem with opennms running a nodejs script in notification
sorry english isn't my main language.
im a beginner at linux and im running a instalation of horizon 33 in a ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine.
what i wnat to do is that opennms runs this script when an outage is detected,
i wrote the command like this in the notificationCommands.xml
but when i try to test it, nothing happens

i also checked the notifd log and it has this error on.

thats why im guessing its a permission problem, but ican't find how to fix it
i've tried:
sudo chown opennms:opennms /run/user/1000/fnm_multishells/4015_1718717187249/bin/node
sudo chmod +x /run/user/1000/fnm_multishells/4015_1718717187249/bin/node
sudo chown opennms:opennms /home/mauri/Scripts/Helpers/app.js
sudo chmod +x /home/mauri/Scripts/Helpers/app.js
i've also tried to run another command like /usr/bin/curl to send a get request to an url to check if al least something could be run it worked fine

i managed to solve this, transforming the service account "opennms" to a normal one.
